# Mongodb - group by same value in different fields in different documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents with common values in different fields that I want to group by that value.  Simplified records are:

```
{ _id:1,
  "Home" : "A",
  "Away" : "B" }

{ _id:2,
  "Home" : "B",
  "Away" : "C" }

{ _id:3,
  "Home" : "C",
  "Away" : "A" }

{ _id:4,
  "Home" : "C",
  "Away" : "B" }

{ _id:5,
  "Home" : "A",
  "Away" : "C" }
```

I am trying to get an aggregate group result that includes, for example, the value "A" whether it appears in a document in the field "Home", or the field "Away".  The result I want is:

```
{"_id": "A", "count": 3},
{"_id": "B", "count": 3},
{"_id": "C", "count": 4}
```

Grouping by either "Home" or "Away" is no problem but that wouldn't give me all the records, as shown below, I wouldn't get a count of records where "A" or "B" or "C" was in the "Home" field:

```
{$group: 
        {_id: "$Away"} etc... }
```

I have tried using $cond from other posts here as follows:

```
$group : {
    _id : {
        $cond : [{
            $gt : [ "$Away", null]
        }, "$Home"]
    }
}
```

Also tried an $or which is pretty obviously wrong since it will only find the same value for Away and Home fields within each document (which is never the case):

```
$group : {
    _id : {
        $or : [ "$Away", "$Home"]
    }
}
```

I'm stuck and not sure if this is even possible; to group on a value that may be in different fields in different documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object to use `$objectToArray` and `$unwind` and then group like this:

- Create object using `$set` and the same values (`$Home` and `$Away`)
- Use project to not pass these values to the next stage. There are no neccesary, you have the object.
- Then `$objectToArray` to do `$unwind` and get every value
- And last `$group` by property `v` generated by `$objectToArray`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "obj": {
        "Home": "$Home",
        "Away": "$Away"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {"Away": 0,"Home": 0}
  },
  {
    "$set": {"obj": {"$objectToArray": "$obj"}}
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$obj"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$obj.v",
      "count": {"$sum": 1}
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Msu4SLtuFCv)

Comment: WOW!  Thank you!  I didn't expect a response so quickly and yet your answer was perfect, even with the simplifications I made in my question, I was able to implement it in a much more complex query (which includes $match, $sort and even $addFields.  Great thanks @J.F.