# MongoDB - Find how many documents have the same characteristics

Tags: mongodb

I'm saying sorry for the title and for not providing an example, but I'm very new to MongoDB and, after trying to accomplish this result using MySQL, I moved to MongoDB because I think that can be simpler to archive this result :(

I'll need to find how many documents have the same "characteristics".

I try to expose this with a restaurant example:
**I need to find the most popular dishes that a family ordered**

This is the dataset, where **persons** and **withChildren** is the criteria of the group by:

```
{"persons": 4, "dish1": 3, "dish2": 4},
{"persons": 4, "dish1": 3, "dish2": 4}, 
{"persons": 4, "dish1": 3, "dish2": 4},

{"persons": 4, "withChilden": true, "dish1": 3, "dish2": 4},

{"persons": 4, "dish1": 3, "dish2": 2},
{"persons": 4, "dish1": 3, "dish2": 2},

{"persons": 4, "dish1": 3, "dish2": 2, "dish3": 6},
```

I make a separation to the rows to better show the difference:

- (4 persons) *has ordered* (dish1=3 / dish2=4) three times
- (4 persons withChilden) *has ordered* (dish1=3 / dish2=4) one time
- (4 persons has ordered) *has ordered* (dish1=3 / dish2=2) two times
- (4 persons has ordered) *has ordered* (dish1=3 / dish2=2 / dish3=6) one time

The goal is to produce documents that expose the previous rows, like that:

```
{
    { "type": {"persons": 4} }, 
    "dish1": 3, 
    "dish2": 4, 
    "tot": 3
}
```

For the type with children, will be:

```
{
    { "type": {"persons": 4, "withChildren": true} }, 
    "dish1": 3, 
    "dish2": 4, 
    "tot": 1
}
```

I'll already try to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232521/mongodb-group-by-same-value-in-different-fields-in-different-documents) solutions, that seems to be a little similar on what I need to accomplish, but because I'm very new to MongoDB I don't know if it's possible to have this result with a single query, if I need to write a script and so on.

The nested object in the result is not trivial, so the result could be a plain object too, like that:

```
{
    "persons": 4, 
    "dish1": 3, 
    "dish2": 4, 
    "tot": 3
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help and understanding

Comment: Using dynamic field names is a poor design. Imagine you have not only 2 different dishes but hundreds or thousands.

Comment: In my case, the dishes will be just 4/5. So from dish1 to dish6 for example. Otherwise, I can adopt another kind of solution?